# Google Sheets API V4 - Adding a tab to the beginning

Tags: php, google-sheets-api

I'm using the following code to add a new tab to my spreadsheet:

```
$newSheetTitie = date("m/d/Y");

$body = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest(array(
   'requests' => array('addSheet' => array('properties' => array('title' => $newSheetTitie )))));

$result = $service->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($spreadsheet_id,$body);
```

This works well, but is there currently any way of adding the new sheet to the beginning of file (prepend it to the other tabs)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about this modification? When you want to add the new sheet to the 1st tab, please use the property of `index` as follows. The 1st tab is `0`.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
$body = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest(array('requests' => array('addSheet' => array('properties' => array('title' => $newSheetTitie )))));
```

To:

```
$body = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest(array('requests' => array('addSheet' => array('properties' => array('title' => $newSheetTitie, 'index' => 0)))));
```

#### References:

- [AddSheetRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#addsheetrequest)
- [SheetProperties](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#SheetProperties)